# class AVPlayerItem was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsarray

**MyCustomView.m**

```
{
   -(IBAction)buttonPlay{
      `Add observer for AVPlayer`
      }
    -(void)dealloc{
      `Remove Observer for AVPlayer`
     }

}
```

**MYViewController.m**

```
{
   for (i=0;i<10;i++){
         myCustomView *m = [[myCustomView alloc]init];
         [arrlist addobject:m];
       }

   -(void)reset{
       [arrList remove allObjects]; //**Crash the app**
     }
}
```

How can I remove object from array. 
I already remove observer in dealloc method but it still not working...

**Thanks for your valuable time**

Answer (score 0):

`dealloc` will not call in `ARC` environment. Instead of put notification observer like below

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                  selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                      name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                                    object:self.playerItem];
```